# Center the login form in the middle of the screen with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get my login form in the middle of the screen and the company logo on the right above. [image]

In the picture this is what I want to make in bootstrap.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        .col-sm-3
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title">
                    Sign In
                </div>
                <div class="forgot-password">
                    <a href="#">Forgot password?</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body body-panel-styling">
                <form class="form-horizontal" id="loginform"></form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img alt="Cerrix" class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/Cerrix-Logo.gif">
    </div>
</div>
```

I already try this website but no luck

https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

How can I center the login form in the middle of the screen and the company logo on the right above side of the screen?

Kind regards

UPDATE: jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/fok6f2fc/

Comment: Bootstrap 3 or 4?

Comment: You have a few unclosed `div` tags there, and I don't see the logo - or any of your CSS, we'll need a MVCE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example) to work with. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: See the CSS of www.ourthing.eu by pressing F12, perhaps you can find the answer inside there. The website uses bootstrap 3.

Comment: @dom_ahdigital bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this match your needs? Login box centered horizontally and vertically with 100% height columns. Best viewed [here on CodePen](https://codepen.io/ahdigital/pen/aVVLVV?editors=1100).

```css
html,body,.container {
  height: 100%;
}

#login-box {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  height: 100%;
  display: table-row;
}

.row .no-float {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.new {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 no-float">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dui augue, sollicitudin et tortor sodales, mollis luctus massa. Praesent non tincidunt neque. Pellentesque facilisis maximus risus, ut porta risus vulputate in. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut neque mi, tincidunt accumsan diam sed, vehicula vulputate ante. Morbi congue purus nulla, a sodales mi pellentesque id. Vestibulum tempor diam cursus nunc convallis, ac vehicula ipsum faucibus. Aenean malesuada pretium est, id laoreet diam aliquam porta. Aenean elementum pharetra leo id consequat. Pellentesque nec odio leo. Donec luctus nibh orci, sit amet malesuada risus suscipit eget. Maecenas aliquet odio nec vulputate vestibulum. Fusce tincidunt enim a mauris ornare, id iaculis nunc luctus. Donec placerat ex in lorem semper faucibus. Praesent ut tempus erat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" id="login-box">
      <div class="new"><div class="panel panel-info">

        <div class="panel-heading">
          <div class="panel-title">Sign In</div>
          <div class="forgot-password"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body body-panel-styling">
          <form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

            <div class="input-group styling-field">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
              <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="username">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group styling-field">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
              <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group styling-button">
              <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Login  </a>
              </div>
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
        </div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 no-float">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dui augue, sollicitudin et tortor sodales, mollis luctus massa. Praesent non tincidunt neque. Pellentesque facilisis maximus risus, ut porta risus vulputate in. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut neque mi, tincidunt accumsan diam sed, vehicula vulputate ante. Morbi congue purus nulla, a sodales mi pellentesque id. Vestibulum tempor diam cursus nunc convallis, ac vehicula ipsum faucibus. Aenean malesuada pretium est, id laoreet diam aliquam porta. Aenean elementum pharetra leo id consequat. Pellentesque nec odio leo. Donec luctus nibh orci, sit amet malesuada risus suscipit eget. Maecenas aliquet odio nec vulputate vestibulum. Fusce tincidunt enim a mauris ornare, id iaculis nunc luctus. Donec placerat ex in lorem semper faucibus. Praesent ut tempus erat.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use flexbox to align the login form to the center of the parent container:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

you'll need to extend the height of the your parent div `<div class="row">` for the centered field to work. assuming you want this container to fill the whole page, you can use viewport units to achieve it:

https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/